# Gradle - list tasks for a subproject

Tags: gradle, subproject

I know I can use `gradle tasks` to list the tasks for a root project.  I inherited a massive project with dozens of subprojects 4-5 levels deep.  Many of the tasks are created dynamically.

How can I list tasks available for a particular subproject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider [this working example](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_64440144).

It has several subprojects, including `system:foo`, which generates spoof tasks for a list of browsers. Note this command-line:

`gradle system:foo:tasks --all`

which will list:

```
[snip]
Other tasks
-----------
fooDownloadDriver_chrome - desc for fooDownloadDriver_chrome
fooDownloadDriver_firefox - desc for fooDownloadDriver_firefox
fooDownloadDriver_safari - desc for fooDownloadDriver_safari
fooGo - desc for fooGo
ijk:ijkGo - desc for ijkGo
```

p.s. The example was tested with Gradle 6.3 and Gradle 5.6.1

Comment: Ah! The `--all` switch was helpful here